# How to implement successive pipes in C?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, parent

I work on a program that downloads the best (marked as '(best)') video format using youtube-dl. It reads a command-line argument then it launches a child process *'youtube-dl -F [url]'*. Then it passes the line with '(best)' to a routine that extracts the format and executes, again as a child, *'youtube-dl -f [best format] [url]'*. The problem is it works only for the first link. Maybe a child doesn't write to a pipe properly, maybe a parent doesn't read from the pipe. I'm lost. Thanks for your help.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LINE_LEN 255

enum { ERROR=-1, CHILD };

void error(char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", msg, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

void dl_best(char *format, char *url)
{
    char fmt[4];
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    for (int i = 0; *format != ' '; format++, i++)
        fmt[i] = *format;
    fmt[3] = '\0';
    switch(pid = fork()) {
    case ERROR:
        error("Failed to pipe in dl_best");
        break;
    case CHILD:
        if (execlp("youtube-dl", "youtube-dl", "-f", fmt, url, NULL) == -1)
            error("Failed to execle() in dl_best");
        break;
    default:
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1)
            error("Waitpid failed in dl_best()");
        break;
    }
}

void get_format(char *url)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2], status;
    char line[LINE_LEN];
    if (pipe(fd) == -1)
        error("Pipe failed");

    if ((pid = fork()) == ERROR) {
        error("Failed to create a child precess in get_format()");
    } else if (pid == CHILD) {
        if (close(fd[0]) == -1)
            error("Child failed to close reading pipe");
        if (dup2(fd[1],1) == -1)
            error("Dup2 failed in get_format()");
        if (execlp("youtube-dl", "youtube-dl", "-F", url, NULL) == -1)
            error("Failed to execute get_formats");
    } else {   //parent
        if (close(fd[1]) == -1)
            error("Parent failed to close writing pipe");
        if (dup2(fd[0],0) == -1)
            error("Dup2 failed in get_format()");
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1)
            error("Waitpid failed in get_format()");
        while (fgets(line, LINE_LEN, stdin)) {   
            if (strstr(line, "(best)") != NULL)
                dl_best(line, url);
        }
        if (close(fd[0]) == -1)
            error("Parent failed to close reading pipe");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //int fd[2], status, argc_cp = argc;
    //dl_best("22 ", argv[--argc]);

    while (--argc) 
        get_format(argv[argc]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not closing enough file descriptors.  The template is `dup2( fd[n], n ); close(fd[0]); close(fd[1])`.  That is, close both ends of the pipe after you dup one.

Comment: How am I supposed to close child's pipe end if it executes another program dies afterwards?

Comment: The whole point of the `dup` is to duplicate the fd.  After you've `dup'd` it, you don't need two copies, and if you fail to close one of them then the reader will never stop blocking, waiting for that last fd to be closed.

Comment: Or, if I misinterpreted your question, you just need to add a `close` between `dup2` and `execl`

Comment: I added close(fd[1]) between dup2 and execl and the program works as before.

Comment: I don't see that you ever add a null-terminator in `fmt`

Comment: Also, it looks like you're trying to write the string "(best)" into an array of size 4.

Comment: Thanks for finding a bug. I added a null terminator to fmt. I write only the first 3 symbols because format is always at the start of the string and it's 3 digits long at max. Even after the fix the program runs as before though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (dup2(fd[0],0) == -1)
        error("Dup2 failed in get_format()");
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == -1)
        error("Waitpid failed in get_format()");
    while (fgets(line, LINE_LEN, stdin)) {   
        if (strstr(line, "(best)") != NULL)
            dl_best(line, url);
    }
```

This is a common mistake when piping from child to parent in C.  With this code, the child will fill up the pipe buffer and then block waiting for the parent to drain the pipe, but the parent won't ever do that because it's blocked waiting for the child to exit, so the overall program will deadlock.
(You won't hit the deadlock for invocations where the child's complete output is smaller than the size of the pipe buffer.  This may be why it appears to work for the first command line argument only.) You need to read all of the data produced by the child *before* you wait for the child to terminate.  For this program, that's as simple as moving the `waitpid` and its conditional below the `while` loop.

Your repeated replacement of file descriptor 0 may also be running foul of the C99 rule that end-of-file is a sticky condition.  (This may also explain why it appears to work for the first command line argument only.)  You *could* address that by calling `clearerr` after the `dup2`, but it would be better not to mess with stdin at all.  Instead, use `fdopen` to convert `fd[0]` into a FILE.

Putting both of those fixes together, your parent-side code in get_format should look something like this:

```
} else {   //parent
    if (close(fd[1]) != 0)
        error("Parent failed to close writing pipe");

    FILE *fp = fdopen(fd[0], "rt");
    if (!fp)
        error("Parent failed to allocate a FILE");

    while (fgets(line, LINE_LEN, fp)) {   
        if (strstr(line, "(best)") != NULL)
            dl_best(line, url);
    }
    if (fclose(fp) != 0)
        error("Parent failed to close reading pipe");

    if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != pid)
        error("Waitpid failed in get_format()");
}
```

(Note that `fd[0]` is closed together with `fp`, by the `fclose`; it is not necessary (in fact, it would be *wrong*) to call `close` on it.)

I would also consider allowing the `dl_best` child to run asynchronously - that is, have `dl_best` return the child PID rather than waiting for it itself, and then `get_format` waits for *both* children after its while loop - but that's an optimization, not a bugfix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and optimization tip. I did just what you suggested but the program downloads just one link as before.

Comment: Your repeated replacement of file descriptor 0 may also be running foul of the C99 rule that end-of-file is a sticky condition. Instead of changing what underlies stdin, use fdopen to convert fd[0] into a FILE. (This may also explain why it appears to work for the first command line argument only.)

I'm not exactly sure how to do that. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Manheim I edited the answer with some sample code.

Comment: Thanks, zwoi! Now it works as intended! What's interesting is that it works properly regardless of the placement of the waitpid command you've talked about earlier.

Comment: You can use [`clearerr(stdin)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clearerr.html) to clear the error and EOF indicators for `stdin`.  If there's a hard failure, they'll be reset; if you've switched to a different file descriptor 0, you'll get to read new information (until the reaches EOF too).

Comment: @Manheim If the placement of waitpid doesn't appear to matter, that means your child process happens not to be producing enough output to fill up the pipe buffer.  It's not something you should rely on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is true but I don't think switching the fd under stdin is good practice when fdopen will do just fine.

Comment: Yes, switching the meaning of file descriptor 0 behind the scenes is riskier than doing the job cleanly — using different file streams at different times.  Using `clearerr()` can help sometimes.  Back in the days of ½ inch magnetic tape drives, you could read up to the first EOF marker, and then read on to the next, and next, using `clearerr()`.